# Similarity between bases of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be vector space above $\mathbb{R}$ and $B = (v_1,v_2,v_3)\quad C = (v_2,v_1,v_3)$ ordered bases of $V$.

Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation.

Prove or disprove $[T]^{b}_c \sim [T]^{c}_b$

I know $[T]^{b}_c=[Id]^{b}_c*[T]^{c}_b*[Id]^{b}_c$ and got the $[Id]$ matrices

I need to use $A=PBP^{-1}$, but not sure how to use it properly.

Maybe I'm wrong so I will be happy get guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence starting with '*I know*' is the key here, as for any bases $B,C$, we have
$$[{\rm Id}]_C^B\cdot [{\rm Id}]_B^C=I$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix, so these are just inverses of each other, and thus you can take $P:=[{\rm Id}]_C^B$.

Here we specifically have
$$[{\rm Id}]_C^B=[{\rm Id}]_B^C=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1}\,,$$
which is indeed its own inverse.